# docker build does not sustain processes

Tags: service, build, docker, daemon

So this might be my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y mysql-server-5.6
RUN service mysql start
RUN service mysql status
```

It throws an error during the build that MySQL is not running, even though the previous command finished with a success. The deamons seem not to be able to be running between different commands in the Dockerfile.

This is an artificial example, but in my real Dockerfile I have lines which configure the database and they need to have a deamon running in the backgroud. The only solution to go around this that I found is to run:

```
RUN service mysql start && ./database_configure1.sh
RUN service mysql start && ./do_something_else_with_db.sh
and so on
```

But this is probably not the way to do it. Is there any better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Each `RUN` command within your Dockerfile runs within a **different container**, so here's the actual sequence of events:

- `service mysql start` starts MySQL.
- Then the container is stopped (MySQL is stopped).
- Then a snapshot is taken.
- Then a new container is launched using that snapshot.
- `service mysql status` is run in the new container.

Of course, `mysql` isn't actually running in the latter container, so that fails.

---

So, instead, you need to do everything **in a single build step**. Usually, you'll want to do this by running a shell script within your container.

Here goes.

Your directory tree should look like this:

```
Dockerfile
do_stuff_with_mysql.sh
```

Then, in your Dockerfile, do:

```
ADD do_stuff_with_mysql.sh /
RUN chmod 755 /do_stuff_with_mysql.sh
RUN do_stuff_with_mysql.sh
```

And, in `do_stuff_with_mysql.sh`, you should have something that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
set -o nounset

service mysql start 
./database_configure1.sh
./do_something_else_with_db.sh
service mysql stop
# you should loop on `service mysql status` to confirm MySQL is done shutting down
```

Comment: I was hoping I am missing something and there's some nifty way to solve this, but this solution is still more elegant than mine :)